# Java and inherited static members

Tags: java, inheritance, static

Suppose i have the below class:

```
class Parent
{
    private int ID;
    private static int curID = 0;

    Parent()
    {
         ID = curID;
         curID++;
    }
}
```

and these two subclasses:

```
class Sub1 extends Parent
{
    //...
}
```

and

```
class Sub2 extends Parent
{
    //...
}
```

My problem is that these two subclasses are sharing the same static curID member from
 parent class, instead of having different ones.

So if i do this:

```
{
    Sub1 r1 = new Sub1(), r2 = new Sub1(), r3 = new Sub1();
    Sub2 t1 = new Sub2(), t2 = new Sub2(), t3 = new Sub2();
}
```

ID's of r1,r2,r3 will be 0,1,2 and of t1,t2,t3 will be 3,4,5.
Instead of these i want t1,t2,t3 to have the values 0,1,2, ie use another copy of curID static variable.

Is this possible? And how?

Comment: Some more details in the discussion:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9898097/what-are-the-rules-dictating-the-inheritance-of-static-variables-in-java

Comment: Some more information
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9898097/what-are-the-rules-dictating-the-inheritance-of-static-variables-in-java

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As others already wrote, static members are bound to the class, so you need to track the id on a class level, e.g. like this:

```
abstract class Parent {
    private int ID;

    Parent() {
         ID = nextId();
    }

    abstract protected int nextId();
}

class Sub1 extends Parent {
    private static int curID = 0;

    protected int nextId() {
       return curID++;
    }

    //...
}

class Sub2 extends Parent {
    private static int curID = 0;

    protected int nextId() {
       return curID++;
    }

    //...
}
```

Note that this approach is not thread safe - but neither was the code in the question. You must not create new objects from the same sub class concurrently from different threads.

Comment: This it a good way to do what the OP needed doing, but I think it is worth mentioning that using static variables in this way is not thread safe. It might be a good idea to use singletons and factory methods here instead.

Comment: @RudolphEst good point - running out of time now but will add this to my answer

Answer (score 15):

While `static` fields/methods are inherited, they cannot be overridden since they belong to the class that declares them, not to the object references. If you try to override one of those, what you'll be doing is hiding it.

Comment: JLS says something diferent: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8

A class C inherits from its direct superclass all concrete methods m (both static and instance) of the superclass

Comment: @MGorgon JLS means that the subclasses will have this method but cannot be overridden since is static, which practically is the same as that the method is not inherited, it is more like the method is imposed.

Comment: I agree with you, but formally JLS strictly specifies that static methods are inherited. It's somewhat confusing, but your answer in oracle certification would be wrong.

Comment: @MGorgon they're not inherited. In fact, you cannot override it, but you can hide it in subclasses.

Comment: 'Cannot override' is not the same thing as 'not inherited'.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza this is wrong, they *are* inherited, but are *not* overridable

Comment: @Eugene fixed...

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza not very sure this *since they belong to the class that declares them* is correct, inheritance means that they belong to the class that inherits them... About the hiding, you could get away from that by declaring it `final` in the parent-class, but then the error from the compiler is just very weird

Answer (score 2):

It is possible, but not using a single counter. You'll need a counter per subtype. For example, something like the following:

```
private static Map<Class<?>, Integer> counters = new HashMap<>();

Parent() {
     Integer curID = counters.get(this.getClass());
     if (curID == null) {
         curID = 0;
     }
     ID = curID;
     curID++;
     counters.put(this.getClass(), curID);
}
```

Beware: the above is not thread-safe. But your initial code isn't either...

Answer (score 1):

Statics are statics are statics.  There is only a single instance of curID, period.  So if you want separate counters for Sub1 and Sub2, you declare the static in each of those classes.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike what other answers said, there IS a solution to your problem, though it doesn't involve "static inheritance". You should have a per-class ID generator.

Here is a good example:

[Java: Parent Methods accessing Subclasses' static variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5394712/java-parent-methods-accessing-subclasses-static-variables?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Static elements are not inherited at all.

There is not actually any such thing as `Sub1.curID` - this is a legal (yet confusing) way of referring to `Persion.curID`.

Unfortunately there isn't any way to do what you're after, with static references.  They fundamentally do not and cannot work with inherentance - since they're statically resolved, they can't rely on dynamic dispatch and so cannot depend on runtime polymorphism.  Given that the JVM/compiler treats static variables this way, I'm confident that there's no workaround you can come up with that would let you do what you want.

If the IDs truly need to be static, then you'll need to define distinct static variables in each of the subclasses.

Comment: JLS says something diferent: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8 A class C inherits from its direct superclass all concrete methods m (both static and instance) of the superclass

Comment: @MGorgon It doesn't *really* inherit the methods - you can't override them, and since static references are resolved at compile time this wouldn't even be possible. It's more like an alias to the superclass' method (I agree that the JLS' language is misleading).  Besides, the issue here isn't with methods but with fields - the behaviour is due to the fact that both subclasses refer to the same `curID` field.

Comment: 'Cannot override' is not the same thing as 'not inherited'.

Answer (score 0):

`static` members are part of the `Parent.class` object in the `PermGen` part of the JVM. All instances of that class **share the same** static variables.

Every subclass should have its own `static curID`.

Comment: Ah, okay. Sorry for a hasty answer.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but it's not only the "instances of the class" that share the same static variable. It's simply all code that can access that variable.

Answer (score -1):

static fields will not be inherited. every instance will use the same field. to accomplish what you want i would change the field into an instance field and either have one instance which internally increments this field or if you need to create three instances you could have a constructor where you pass the incremented value.

Answer (score -1):

You are using a `static` variable

- There are no copies of `static` variable for different objects,
- There will be only on copy of `static` variable and it will be shared for all the instances

Regarding static variable inheritance, **They are not inheritd at all**

So even if you say

```
r1.curID;
t1.curID;
```

It will mean the same thing, i.e. `Parent.curID`

When you are changing a `static` variable from the instance of the class, and if another instance is accessing that variable, it will get the changed value as its a shared variable