# Grails domains inheriting abstract classes hasMany

Tags: grails, inheritance, abstract, grails-domain-class

So I'm attempting to let 2 domains inherit from a single domain.

```
abstract class Pet {
    Nose nose
    static hasMany = [legs: Leg]
}

class Dog extends Pet {
    static hasMany = [friends: Friend]
}
```

And I'm getting an error:

```
Caused by: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.InvalidPropertyException: No property found for name [legs] for class [class animals.Dog]
```

Any ideas? Is there something I have to do to combine the hasManys?

Comment: What version of Grails are you using and where is the Pet class defined (e.g. src/groovy or grails-app/domain)?

Comment: 2.2.4 and Pet is defined in src/groovy

Answer (score 0):

I tried replicating the problem and I did not get an `InvalidPropertyException`, but the database schema that was generated was missing the 1:m relationship between `Dog` and `Leg`.

I believe the problem is related to `Pet` being an abstract class.  If the `Dog` class inherits `Set legs` from `Pet`, then in order to persist the `Leg` instances to the database,  the underlying `Leg` table needs to have a foreign key of `pet_id`**.  Since `Pet` is an `abstract` class, a table is not created for it and therefore no `id` column.  Therefore, no foreign key can be created in the dependent class, `Leg`.

Making the `Pet` class a concrete class (moving it to `grails-app/domain` and removing the `abstract` keyword), means that a table with an `id` field will be created.  And in the `Leg` table, a `pet_id` column can/will be created that Hibernate will use to persist/retrieve the `Set legs`.

** (or an associative entity table, such as `pet_legs`, would need to have the foreign key)

Making the `Pet` class concrete, however, will cause all the sub-classes of `Pet` to be stored into that table, so if you want each sub-class to have its own table, you could add:

```
  static mapping = {
    tablePerHierarchy false
  }
```

to the `Dog` class, which will create a `Pet`, `Dog`, etc table in the db.

Comment: I never wanted a `pet_id` field to use as a foreign key, I just want the properties of Pet to be inherited by `Dog`.

Comment: Sorry, my original answer may have been a bit cryptic, so I expanded on it to explain what I meant by the `pet_id` issue.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a couple of things:

1. GORM won't generate table relationships for an `abstract` class
2. [`static` fields/methods are not inherited. They belong to the class, not to the object references](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17172112/1242842)

So you have to change the code to one of the following:

```
abstract class Pet {
    Nose nose
}

class Dog extends Pet {
    static hasMany = [legs: Leg, friends: Friend]
}
```

or

```
abstract class Pet {
    Nose nose
    static hasMany = [legs: Leg]
}

class Dog extends Pet {
    static hasMany = [friends: Friend] + Pet.hasMany
}
```

Yes the second approach works because you can *initialize static members of a class by another static classe's static member*.