# Which classes get initialized when a static method of Base class is called through Derived class reference?

Tags: java, static-initialization

I think that only Base class is initialized when `Derived.f()` is called. *Exactly like it happens when we have a (non-compile-time-constant) static field in Base*, not static method. My doubt is only that JLS is not very clear on that.

```
class Base {
    static void f() {}
}

class Derived extends Base {

}

Derived.f(); // called legally from some other class
```

*According to JLS (see below), it seems that only Base class is initialized.* But do I read and understand JLS correctly?

I also know that in the case with (non-compile-time-constant) static fields only class where static field is *defined* is initialized (static initializers called):

```
class Base {
    static int x = 1;
}

class Derived extends Base {

}

//somewhere in some other class
int y = Derived.x;  // triggers only Base to be initialized
```

> **[12.4.1. When Initialization Occurs (JLS)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4)**
>
> A class or interface type T will be initialized immediately before the
>   first occurrence of any one of the following:
>
> T is a class and an instance of T is created.
>
> **T is a class and a static method *declared* by T is invoked.**
>
> A static field declared by T is assigned.
>
> A static field declared by T is used and the field is not a constant
>   variable (§4.12.4).
>
> T is a top level class (§7.6), and an assert statement (§14.10)
>   lexically nested within T (§8.1.3) is executed.
>
> *A reference to a static field (§8.3.1.1) causes initialization of only
>   the class or interface that actually declares it, even though it might
>   be referred to through the name of a subclass, a subinterface, or a
>   class that implements an interface.*  **BUT JLS DOES NOT STATE HERE THE SAME ABOUT STATIC METHODS THOUGH !**

Besides, [12.4. Initialization of Classes and Interfaces says clearly](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4):

> **Before a class is initialized, its direct superclass must be initialized**

*And an exclusion from this rule is given by JLS only for static fields, not static methods!*

Initializing both Base and Derived seemingly would make sense - if f() uses any static fields inside its body, then Derived.f() will be using static fields of Derived (if any), and may use static fields inherited from Base (if Derived has none) - which makes sense to initialize both classes.

***After all, simple test shows that only Base class is initialized:***

```
class Base {
    static { System.out.println("Base init"); }

    static void f() {}
}

class Derived extends Base {
    static { System.out.println("Derived init"); }
}

public class Driver {
    public static void main(String[] args)  {
        Derived.f(); // Only "Base init" printed...
    }
}
```

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2831426/5267751)?

Comment: By word  "initialized" what do you mean?

Comment: @AmitBera JLS 12.4.1. When Initialization Occurs - when static initializers run (not constructor and not instance initializers).

Comment: @user202729 - No, not related directly to the question.

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you are asking. Could you point which statement of JLS making you confused ?

Comment: Check decompiled code, `Derived.x` can be compiled as `Base.x`

Comment: I guess [only the parent gets initialized](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17172112/6367213)... but the specs are confusing at best!

Comment: You already highlighted the relevant word, initialization occurs when “a static method ***declared*** by T is invoked.”, so when you call `Derived.f()`, it’s still invoking a method *declared by `Base`*.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the confusion is about how member variables, including static member variables, work in Java.  Unlike methods, member variables in derived classes do not inherit their super class counterparts; they merely shadow them.  Thus, if you have a variable `foo` in `Base` and a variable `foo` in `Derived`, then if you print that variable in `Base` you will get the version in `Base`, and if you print from `Derived`, you get the version in `Derived`.

```
public class MyTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Base.f();
        Derived.f();
    }
}

class Base {
    static void f() {
        System.out.println("bar = " + bar);
    }

    protected static int bar = 1;
}

class Derived extends Base {
    static void f() {
        System.out.println("bar = " + bar);
    }

    private static int bar = 2;
}
```

gives:

```
bar = 1
bar = 2
```

So, there is no reason to run the initializers in `Derived` when you call a static method in `Base` because `Base` could never directly access the variables in `Derived`.