# How can I make a protected static field public in sub class?

Tags: java, class, inheritance, static

I have this code:

```
class A {
    protected static final String foo = "FOO";
}

class B extends A {
    public static final String foo;
}
```

I expect `System.out.println(B.foo)` to print `FOO` but it prints `null`.

I know that I can get around this by replacing the field declaration in `B` with a method like:

```
class B extends A {
    public static final String foo() { return foo; }
}
```

Is it possible to inherit a protected static field and make it public?

The class B is used as a mock object, and adding those parenthesis so the call is `B.foo()` instead of `B.foo` does not really matter, but I was just interested if it was possible to get rid of them, and if yes, if there is a good reason not to do that. Or if my approach is completely wrong in some other way.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17172033/java-and-inherited-static-members

Answer (score 3):

> I expect `System.out.println(B.foo)` to print `FOO` but it prints `null`.

That is because `B.foo` does not override `A.foo`; instead, it shadows `A.foo` - in other words, `B.foo` is a new variable, separate from `A.foo`, that just happens to have the same name.

Variables cannot be overridden, and static methods cannot be overridden.

Only non-static methods can be overridden in a subclass.

> Is it possible to inherit a protected static field and make it public?

No.

Comment: Fair enough. I use the methods then. Thanks.